# How can I bring two variables from php to jQuery (on separate values).

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is confusing and i've read documentation and some other questions here in StackOverFlow. And I just don't understand (Or the answers doesn't fit my need)

Here's the thing: I have a php with two values from a SQL query. So far, everything is great. I have them in two separate values.

Here's a piece of the two values:

```
$puntoslocal = json_encode($reglocal["puntaje"]);
$puntosvisitante = json_encode($regvisitante["puntaje"]);
```

But I need in Javascript (using or not jQuery) to get these two values ($puntoslocal and $puntosvisitante). Here's where i get lost.

How can I bring these two separate values in two separate vars?

Thank you so much, I know this may sound silly, but I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: Are you using AJAX to return the results or does this same script also generate the html/javascript output to load the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as easy as an array

```
$arr = array(
    "puntoslocal"     => $reglocal["puntaje"],
    "puntosvisitante" => $regvisitante["puntaje"]
)

echo json_encode( $arr );
```

Comment: Hi! :) .... I tried this, and this may sound silly too, but how do I call that array from Js?.... Do I need to use ajax? How can I do that.... I don't understand :( :( Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can get the 2 variables using an **ajax request** or putting them along with **HTML**.

Try this in your php file:

```
<script>
puntoslocal = '<?php echo $puntoslocal; ?>';
puntosvisitante = '<?php echo $puntosvisitante; ?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If needed, can be done without json too, by concatenating the two strings and split them in jquery:
In your php-file:

```
echo $arr[0].":".$arr[1];
```

and jquery:

```
success: function(data){
      if(data){
         var myarr = data.split(":");
         $('#div1').html(myarr[0]);
         $('#div2').html(myarr[1]);
      }
  }
```

Note: use another divider when your vars contain the :